# Select transformation to table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data from select query which looks this way:

```
         Id                               EventName  Quantity
A930FF06-B9F2-4D06-A28E-00037E82DDB1    DiscountClick   40
A930FF06-B9F2-4D06-A28E-00037E82DDB1    DiscountLike    1
A930FF06-B9F2-4D06-A28E-00037E82DDB1    DiscountSave    11
A930FF06-B9F2-4D06-A28E-00037E82DDB1    DiscountView    2579
28D64EEB-97FB-45A9-AA4C-00359FF6FF42    DiscountClick   22
28D64EEB-97FB-45A9-AA4C-00359FF6FF42    DiscountSave    1
28D64EEB-97FB-45A9-AA4C-00359FF6FF42    DiscountView    971
```

I want transform it to table which looks this:

```
 Id                                     DiscountView   Discount...
A930FF06-B9F2-4D06-A28E-00037E82DDB1    2579
28D64EEB-97FB-45A9-AA4C-00359FF6FF42    971
```

How I can do that?

Comment: you are looking for `PIVOT`

Comment: Will there only be the three options?

Answer (score 1):

This is the dynamic pivot query for your problem.

```
  DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @PivotColumnNames AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @PivotSelectColumnNames AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

--Get distinct values of the PIVOT Column
SELECT @PivotColumnNames= ISNULL(@PivotColumnNames + ',','')
+ QUOTENAME(EventName)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT EventName FROM test_table) AS Courses

--Get distinct values of the PIVOT Column with isnull
SELECT @PivotSelectColumnNames 
    = ISNULL(@PivotSelectColumnNames + ',','')
    + 'ISNULL(' + QUOTENAME(EventName) + ', 0) AS '
    + QUOTENAME(EventName)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT EventName FROM test_table) AS Courses

--Prepare the PIVOT query using the dynamic 
SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 
  N'SELECT Id, ' + @PivotSelectColumnNames + '
    FROM test_table
    pivot(sum(quantity) for EventName in (' + @PivotColumnNames + ')) as pvt';

--Execute the Dynamic Pivot Query
EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```

[image]

Comment: What about not NULL but 0 for it?

Comment: Invalid column name 'quantity'.

Comment: change the column name of 'quantity' as in your table accordingly

Answer (score 0):

This is the traditional cross tab / conditional aggregation version of a `pivot()`:

```
select
    Id
  , DiscountView = sum(case when EventName = 'DiscountView' then Quantity end)
  , DiscountSave = sum(case when EventName = 'DiscountSave' then Quantity end)
  , DiscountLike = sum(case when EventName = 'DiscountLike' then Quantity end)
from t
group by Id
```

`pivot()` version:

```
select
    Id
  , DiscountView
  , DiscountSave
  , DiscountLike
from t
pivot (sum(Quantity) for EventName in (DiscountView, DiscountSave, DiscountLike)) pvt
```

Comment: T slow. I have it already with variables. and case then else condition.

Comment: @Nerf Okay, I'm not sure what you are trying to say, but thanks for the downvote.

Comment: this answer is more useful. I VoteUp. 
If you want to run it from c # you may have problems
son no database dependency, simple query write and run if the query is late can be Improvement . @Nerf